# Not able to mount network drive on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, network-drive

I have connected Hard disk to my router D-Link DSL-2750U with **anonymous access**. I am able to access the drive using "smb://192.168.1.1/" from file browser on Ubuntu **without any username or password**.

But when I try to mount it using CIFS using below command

sudo mount -t cifs -o //192.168.1.1/ ./usb-network-drive/

It always asks me for password. Even when I provide it password configured on router for root user it throws me below error

```
L501X:~$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/ ./usb-network-drive/ -o rw
Password for root@//192.168.1.1/: 
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I am also able to view it using smbclient command as below

```
L501X:~$ smbclient -L 192.168.1.1 --no-pass
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.27a]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    usb1_1          Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.27a]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

Can someone please help me mounting network drive on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Comment: Is 192.168.1.1 the drive or the router?

Comment: Its router address , USB drive connected to router. I am able to access it via "smb://192.168.1.1/" from Ubuntu file browser. but not able to mount it

Comment: You need the share name of the drive In the mount command after the URL like //192.168.1.1/the-share-name /themount-point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the share name of the drive after the URL like

> sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/share-name /mount-point -o [options]